WhatsApp Flows DatePicker
I wish to implement a date picker logic for WhatsApp flows where in the age entered by user should be in range 18 years to 60 years additionally the date option should not be more that todays date

If you need the exact date, then following options might be the best way to achieve this:

Use data exchange and return min/max dates from server
Pass today's date when sending a flow message as part of initial payload along with screen name.

If you don’t need the exact date, then you can use text input to enter age and limit the value from 18 to 60
